# Who among you watch or watches?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I know that the word "who" can both refer to a singular or a plural noun. The thing that makes me confused is the word "you" in the following sentences. Should it be followed by a singular or a plural verb? Haven't had any luck in searching for the precise answer. Thank you!

- Who among you watch this show?
- Who among you watches this show?

Comment: Instead of just asking if these are correct or not, explain why you think they might or might not be. Then we can reopen this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be **Who among you watches this show?**

*Who* is the subject and takes the singular verb, *among you* is a prepositional phrase and *you* is not actually the subject of the verb.

It's similar to *Who in the world likes pumpkin?* I realize that many people (not me) do, but still ask the question with Who likes...

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an *all* right after the *who* as in:

> Who among you all watch this show?

They aren't referring to a singular you rather a plural.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. The phrase **who among you** is somewhat formal and old-fashioned. You're more likely to see it in books written in centuries past, and if you do hear it, it will probably be out of the mouth of a preacher standing at the pulpit, not from the presenter at a TED-talk.

But let's make it contemporary anyway:

> Who among you has seen *Jurassic Park*?
>
> Who among you are Tottenham fans?

Answer (score 0):

Both can be correct but treating "who" as singular is more common:

> "Who among you watches"... (154 Google hits)
>
> "Who among you watch"... (12 Google hits)